# Visual Studio 2013 and Angular

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gulp, yeoman

I need to work with Visual Studio 2013.
I have already an scaffoldded Angular + Gulp project created with yeoman
Now i need to edit with visual studio.

Could you please explain me how to enable angular on Visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "enable" angular for VS.
It is just editing text files in a certain folder structure.
Just import the folder as a new project or whatever suits your needs.
(In theory you could develop an Angular app with any text editor).
If you need intellisense or other helping technology look for an appropriate add-on on nuget. (e.g. [ng intellisense Add-on](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/) )